# Section processing failed

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization, light-clients

I am trying to connect a geth node to the network for several days with light sync, and I have encountered a lot of problems.
The last to date is there are a lot (like > 100) of error messages that look like:

`Section processing failed type=bloombits error="cannonical block #4227072 unknown"`

What does it mean? And what can I do?

Comment: did you find a fix for this error ?

Comment: @KakiMasterOfTime no, I didn't.